# Why is my if statement not working in this grading code?

Tags: python

This is my code, I want it to go through and choose what category it fits in but it always gives me F.

```
import random

def rand(start, stop):
  print random.randint(start,stop)

def grader(rand):
  print "Your test score is "
  x = rand(50, 100)
  if x >= 90:
    print "which is an A."
  elif x <= 89 and x >= 80:
    print "which is a B."
  elif x <= 79 and x >= 70:
    print "which is a C."
  elif x <= 69 and x >=60:
    print "which is a D."
  else:
    print "which is a F."
```

Comment: `print` is not `return`.

Comment: Why do you need your own function that does exactly the same thing as `random.randint()`?

Comment: My teacher had me put that in :/

Comment: [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) ,

Answer (score 0):

Your `rand` function is returning `None` since it is printing a value, instead of returning it. Also, good practice would be to name it something more descriptive, such as `get_random` or `get_random_number`. Also, your `get_random` function does the exact same thing `randint` does, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt there (*more functionality to be added?*).

As a bonus, I've included an example how the little known `bisect` library is perfect for these kinds of value intersection problems!

**Example:**

```
import bisect, random

def get_random(start, stop):
  return random.randint(start,stop)

def match_grade(score):
    breakpoints = [60, 70, 80, 90]
    grades = ["which is a F.", "which is a D.", 
    "which is a C.", "which is a B.", "which is an A."]
    bisect_index = bisect.bisect(breakpoints, score)
    return grades[bisect_index]

random_number = get_random(50, 100)
grade_range = match_grade(random_number)
print "Your test score is {}, {}".format(random_number, grade_range)
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Your test score is 63, which is a D.
```